# How to able login to app using Microsoft?

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine, authentication, integration

As you can see, I make a UI layout of the authorization page in applications for my company employees.

Yes, of course, I can add a link so that after clicking on the "login with Microsoft" button, there is will be redirected to the Microsoft login page.

I making an app for our office, and we use Microsoft accounts to work, but I don't know how to link my app and Microsoft authorization.

Maybe anyone has any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgKgr.png)

Comment: Look up "Open ID Connect"

Comment: Or possibly microsoft OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see your image or anything that perhaps you tried to add. But I believe that what you are trying to build is a B2C application in Azure AD. You will need to configure your application as an authorized application in your organization's tenant subscription.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/quickstart-web-app-dotnet